# JavaScript Music Player with progress bar?

Tags: javascript, flash

I am creating a little JavaScript music player that sits on the btottom of the page, a lot like [streampad](http://www.streampad.com/).  But streampad uses a flash progress bar for the song and JavaScript for everything else and I am having a hard time finding anyone who does this with JavaScript alone.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how this can be done (preferably without using HTML5)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do this with just Javascript, without going into html5 (the audio tag).

[SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) has a hidden flash component, and the UI is completely in JS. It's up to you to implement a seekbar or whatever you want, but there's a whole lot of example code. SM2 seems pretty popular, and is used by a number of big sites (Soundcloud, Last.fm, Muxtape).

Answer (score 1):

i think you may found usefull look at theese:

[Monitoring Loading Progress of SWFs](http://www.webreference.com/js/tips/010526.html)

http://code.google.com/p/swfsound/

> SWFSound is based on SWFObject and
>   allows cross-plattform, cross-browser
>   sound support for HTML/JavaScript
>   using Flash Player 8 and higher.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

> SWFObject is an easy-to-use and
>   standards-friendly method to embed
>   Flash content, which utilizes one
>   small JavaScript file

just some example

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/

http://www.bauer.uh.edu/parks/video3.htm

Comment: Thanks, I'd prefer not to use a plugin and just do something custom, but this is still cool to look into.

Comment: Jplayer looks pretty neat, does html5 with a fallback to flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without HTML 5 or Flash.

You could however create an hidden flash player and control it via javascript using External Interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a library that implements a progress bar using html5 and javascript, see RGraph: http://www.rgraph.net/examples/progress.html

Comment: I've thought about this, but need a backup, so I guess I might have to do html5 and flash. That's annoying.